# SQL how to merge records Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table which is something like the below

```
Key CL  EmailAddress    CT  Product1    Product2    Product3    Product4    Product5
1   X   abc@gmail.com   A   12          null        null        null        null
2   X   abc@gmail.com   B   123         22          null        null      null
```

For each row I can have a maximum of 5 products. Each record would have a minimum of 1 but less than 5 products.

Also the email address can repeat across the same CL.

I would have to write a query to find if the email address repeats across the same CL and if it does

I would have to merge the productids for the same email address.

On doing the merge if I have got 5 products I need to stop and exclude the remaining products.

So the output for the above example should look something like this

```
Key CL  EmailAddress    CT  Product1    Product2    Product3    Product4    Product5
1   X   abc@ gmail.com  A+B 12          123         22          null     null
```

Can we do something like this in Oracle SQL query?

Comment: the output makes no sense at all. I don't see any logic in it.

Comment: The logic behind your needed result is not clear. Please explain what should be the idea for such a result; what are you groupin for? mail and CL? Key=1 because it is the minimum value? why product1=12, product2=123 and product3=22?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an alternative to MTO's approach, you could unpivot the data from your table:

```
select *
from your_table
unpivot (product for pos in (product1 as 1, product2 as 2, product3 as 3,
  product4 as 4, product5 as 5));

       KEY CL EMAILADDRESS  CT         POS    PRODUCT
---------- -- ------------- --- ---------- ----------
         1 X  abc@gmail.com A            1         12
         2 X  abc@gmail.com B            1        123
         2 X  abc@gmail.com B            2         22
```

Use that to pick the key and generate the CT value (shamelessly pinching MTO's regular expression to remove duplicates), and generating a new position value:

```
with t as (
  select *
  from your_table
  unpivot (product for pos in (product1 as 1, product2 as 2, product3 as 3,
    product4 as 4, product5 as 5))
)
select min(key) over (partition by cl, emailaddress) as key,
  cl,
  emailaddress,
  regexp_replace(
    listagg(ct, '+') within group (order by key) over (partition by cl, emailaddress),
    '(.)(\+\1)+', '\1') as ct,
  rank() over (partition by cl, emailaddress order by key, pos) as pos,
  product
from t;

       KEY CL EMAILADDRESS  CT         POS    PRODUCT
---------- -- ------------- --- ---------- ----------
         1 X  abc@gmail.com A+B          1         12
         1 X  abc@gmail.com A+B          2        123
         1 X  abc@gmail.com A+B          3         22
```

And then finally pivot that back:

```
with t as (
  select *
  from your_table
  unpivot (product for pos in (product1 as 1, product2 as 2, product3 as 3,
    product4 as 4, product5 as 5))
)
select key, cl, emailaddress, ct, a_product as product1, b_product as product2,
  c_product as product3, d_product as product4, e_product as product5
from (
  select min(key) over (partition by cl, emailaddress) as key,
    cl,
    emailaddress,
    regexp_replace(
      listagg(ct, '+') within group (order by key) over (partition by cl, emailaddress),
      '(.)(\+\1)+', '\1') as ct,
    rank() over (partition by cl, emailaddress order by key, pos) as pos,
    product
  from t
)
pivot (max(product) as product for (pos) in (1 as a, 2 as b, 3 as c, 4 as d, 5 as e));

       KEY CL EMAILADDRESS  CT    PRODUCT1   PRODUCT2   PRODUCT3   PRODUCT4   PRODUCT5
---------- -- ------------- --- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1 X  abc@gmail.com A+B         12        123         22
```

It's made slightly more complicated by making the column names in the final result match your original table. I've also assumed you want to keep the lowest key value, link the CT values in key order, and keep the products in the same order they appeared originally - or at least, with the products from the first key in their original order, followed by the products from the second key in *their* original order, etc.

Answer (score 3):

**Oracle Setup**

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  "Key"        INT PRIMARY KEY,
  CL           CHAR(1),
  EmailAddress VARCHAR2(100),
  CT           VARCHAR2(100),
  Product1     INT,
  Product2     INT,
  Product3     INT,
  Product4     INT,
  Product5     INT
);

INSERT INTO table_name
SELECT 1, 'X', 'abc@gmail.com', 'A', 12,  null, null, null, null FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'X', 'abc@gmail.com', 'B', 123,   22, null, null, null FROM DUAL;

CREATE TYPE stringlist AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(100);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION nth_item(
  collection STRINGLIST,
  n          INT
) RETURN VARCHAR2 DETERMINISTIC
AS
BEGIN
  IF collection IS NULL OR n < 1 OR n > collection.COUNT THEN
    RETURN NULL;
  END IF;
  RETURN collection(n);
END;
/
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT "Key",
       CL,
       EmailAddress,
       CT,
       Nth_Item( products, 1 ) AS Product1,
       Nth_Item( products, 2 ) AS Product2,
       Nth_Item( products, 3 ) AS Product3,
       Nth_Item( products, 4 ) AS Product4,
       Nth_Item( products, 5 ) AS Product5
FROM   (
  SELECT MIN( "Key" ) AS "Key",
         CL,
         EmailAddress,
         REGEXP_REPLACE(
           LISTAGG( CT, '+' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY CT ),
           '(.)(\+\1)+',
           '\1'
         ) AS CT,
         CAST( COLLECT( COLUMN_VALUE ) AS stringlist ) AS products
  FROM   table_name t,
         TABLE(
           STRINGLIST(
             t.Product1,
             t.Product2,
             t.Product3,
             t.Product4,
             t.Product5
           )
         )
  WHERE  COLUMN_VALUE IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY CL, EmailAddress
);
```

**Output**:

```
Key CL EMAILADDRESS  CT  PRODUCT1 PRODUCT2 PRODUCT3 PRODUCT4 PRODUCT5
--- -- ------------- --- -------- -------- -------- -------- --------
  1 X  abc@gmail.com A+B       12       22      123
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option:

```
with test_data(Key1, CL,  EmailAddress,    CT,  Product1,    Product2,    Product3,    Product4,    Product5)
as (
select 1, 'X', 'abc@gmail.com', 'A', 12 , null, null, null, null from DUAL union all
select 2, 'X', 'abc@gmail.com', 'B', 12 , 123,  null, null, null from DUAL   
)

select 
  min(KEY1) as KEY1,
  CL,
  EmailAddress,
  case when instr(min(CT1), '+', 1, 5) = 0
       then min(CT1)
       else substr(min(CT1), 1, instr(min(CT1), '+', 1, 5)-1)
  end CT,
  max(PRODUCT1) PRODUCT1,
  max(PRODUCT2) PRODUCT2,
  max(PRODUCT3) PRODUCT3,
  max(PRODUCT4) PRODUCT4,
  max(PRODUCT5) PRODUCT5
from
(
  select * from
    (
      select t.*, 
      row_number() over (partition by CL,EmailAddress order by key1) RN
      FROM
      (
         select *  from 
         ( 
           select temp.*,
                  listagg(CT,'+') within group (order by key1) over (partition by CL, EmailAddress) CT1
           from test_data temp
         )
         unpivot
         (prod FOR col in (PRODUCT1,PRODUCT2,PRODUCT3,PRODUCT4,PRODUCT5))
         order by KEY1
      ) t
    ) t1
    where RN <=5
  ) 
  pivot
  (
    min(prod)
    for RN in (1 as PRODUCT1,2 as PRODUCT2,3 as PRODUCT3,4 as PRODUCT4,5 as PRODUCT5)
  )      
group by CL, EmailAddress
;
```